# How to align the cancel button such that it should be in sync with the varying table size?

Tags: java, css

Actually, I have a table, where the number of rows in the table increases/decreases dynamically. So I want to position my submit button appropriately. Please advice.
This is what I am trying:
In my servlet I am trying to include it:

```
 "input[type=button] {"+
                     "position:absolute;"+
                     "transition: .5s ease;"+
                     "top: 80%;"+
                      "left: 75%;"+
                      "font-size: 22px;"+ 
                      "font-weight: bold;"+
                      "font-family: ariel;"+ 
                      "background-color: #ffedca;"+
                      "}"+
```

But this worked fine if I have 2 or 3 rows in my table. But if I have more than 3 rows,
The output will be:

```
            1   CPA1        Validating      release                
            2   CPA2        Validating      release
            3   CPA3        Validating      release  cancel  ok
            4   CPA4        Validating      release
```

In the above output, the cancel and ok buttons are in 3 rows only.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you may be able to work in a structure that would be something like

```
<body>
  <div class="form">
    <input>
      ...some input fields
    </input>
    <button>My Submit</button>
  </div>
<body>
```

then your css

```
.form{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

this would center all children in your .form div vertically and horizontally in the .form without having to specify padding or margin

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a bit late, but you could do do it in the following way:

```css
tr{
   height: 10px;
   width:100px;
 }
 table{
   width: 100%;
 }
 table, tr, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 .container{
  display: flex;
 }
 .tableContainer{
  width:80%;
 }
 .submitContainer{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width:20%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class='tableContainer'>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div class='submitContainer'>
  <button>CLick me </button>
 </div>
</div>
```